# check if tree is binary search one with duplicates allowed on the left

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have this function to check if a tree is a binary search one, it assumes a binary search doesn't allow duplicates, but what if we want to allow duplicates on the left children, how can we handle this case with this recursive solution:

```
int is_bst(Node* root, int min, int max) { 
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (root->data < max && root->data > min && is_bst(root->left, min, root->data) && is_bst(root->right, root->data, max)) 
        return 1;
    else
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: One simple way to keep the normal properties of a BST but still allow duplicates, is to simply add a counter to each node. When a duplicate is added, just increase the counter instead of adding a new node. Once you allow duplicate nodes, then the tree isn't a BST any more.

Comment: "have this function to check if a tree is a binary search one, it assumes a binary search doesn't allow duplicates, " --> It also does not allow  data to be `INT_MIN`, or `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude counter works with "multiset", but not "map" (key to payload).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the current node is between `min` and `max` (both **included**). When going left, allow the max to be equal to the current node and when going right, require that the min is at least the current node+1:

```
int is_bst(Node* root, int min, int max) { 
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (root->data <= max && root->data >= min && is_bst(root->left, min, root->data) && is_bst(root->right, root->data+1, max)) 
        return 1;
    else
        return 0; 
}
```